# Groovy @SelfType generating error with runtime traits

Tags: groovy

If I run the code below

```groovy
import groovy.transform.SelfType

interface StringProvider {
    String getString()
}

class MyStringProvider implements StringProvider {
    @Override
    String getString() {
        "MyString"
    }
}

//@SelfType(StringProvider)
trait DoubleStringProvider {
    String getDoubleString() {
        String s = getString()
        s + s
    }
}


MyStringProvider provider = new MyStringProvider()
println "provider = ${provider} (${provider.class})"
def doubleProvider = provider.withTraits DoubleStringProvider
println "doubleProvider = ${doubleProvider} (${doubleProvider.class})"
println "getDoubleString() ${doubleProvider.getDoubleString()}"
```

it displays

> provider = MyStringProvider@213860b8 (class MyStringProvider)
> doubleProvider = MyStringProvider5_groovyProxy@3d36dff4 (class
> MyStringProvider5_groovyProxy) getDoubleString() MyStringMyString

when I uncomment the @SelfType statement I get

> provider = MyStringProvider@476a736d (class MyStringProvider)
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: DoubleStringProvider$TraitAdapterwrapper: -1: class
> 'DoubleStringProvider$TraitAdapter' implements trait
> 'DoubleStringProvider' but does not implement self type interface
> 'StringProvider'  @ line -1, column -1. 1 error
>
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:311)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ProcessingUnit.completePhase(ProcessingUnit.java:149)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$20.call(CompilationUnit.java:938)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:965)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:601)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProxyGeneratorAdapter.adjustSuperClass(ProxyGeneratorAdapter.java:225)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ProxyGeneratorAdapter.(ProxyGeneratorAdapter.java:160)
> at groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.createAdapter(ProxyGenerator.java:230)
> at
> groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:205)
> at
> groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegateWithBaseClass(ProxyGenerator.java:189)
> at
> groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:181)
> at
> groovy.util.ProxyGenerator.instantiateDelegate(ProxyGenerator.java:177)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.withTraits(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:19602)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$841.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:49)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
> at ideaGroovyConsole.run(ideaGroovyConsole.groovy:25)   at
> groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:266)
> at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:376)    at
> groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:355)     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:167)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
> at console.run(console.groovy:11)   at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processReader(GroovyMain.java:571)   at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processFiles(GroovyMain.java:490)    at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:334)     at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.access$1400(GroovyMain.java:69)  at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain$GroovyCommand.process(GroovyMain.java:295)   at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:134)     at
> groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:116)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:110)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)

I understand what the error is saying but how do I make it work?

`def doubleProvider = (provider as StringProvider).withTraits DoubleStringProvider` doesn't work but was worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/transform/SelfType.html, you need to use @SelfType annotation when you want to compile the class statically. In your case you are adding the traits dynamically, so you don't have to worry about this. Moreover, (not 100% sure though) the annotation parameter requires class name not the interface name as compiler has to make sure that the given method has really been implemented!

Comment: yes, you would need to use @SelfType if compiling the class statically. I'm not compiling statically so it isn't required. It is still useful though.